# Timezone related issue with asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have one existing ASP.NET application. This application built in .net framework 2.0

We used DateTime.Now at many places to store current datetime in application. Its for different purposes including logging.

Currently application hosted on server which of USA. When I access application from my machine, it returns current datetime of server. Is there any way, I can get my local machine.

I researched and got that I need to use TimeZone class to get current datetime of my local machine. But in that case, I need to change wherever I used Datetime.Now and get time from timezone.

Is there any way, I can set globally and when I use datetime.now, it returns local machine time?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. There is no way to set TimeZone globally.

Best options:

- Convert DateTime.Now to DateTime.UtcNow and do the appropriate
  calculations (what if you have to move the server to another zone of
  US?)
- Use DateTimeOffset insted of DateTime which use the TimeZone.

In any case, you have to handle the date time conversion to the local time zone in client side of you app, not in the server side.

Comment: Yes. I did same thing. I created one common function which returns local date based on timezone instead of server date. But problem is now wherever I have used datetime.now, I need to update update code and need to use that common function. I am looking for any alternative so that I don't need to update everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could also possibly set the timezone on the server itself to the one you need.